# wordpress feed displaying full posts instead of excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, feed

I've been implementing a way to get the feature images to display in the rss feed for automated newsletters to retrive them, and I've managed that by adding the following snippet:

```
function rss_post_thumbnail($content) {
global $post;
if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
$content = '<p>' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID) .
'</p>' . get_the_content();
}
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'rss_post_thumbnail');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'rss_post_thumbnail');
```

It didn't seemed to work until I left it running overnight and when I woke up and refressed the feed, the feature images corresponding img tag started to display correctly as I wanted in the feed.

BUT

Somehow the feed is now displaying the entire full text content of the articles instead of just an excerpt as it used to. I've already went to my Wordpress dashboard to Options > Reading > article feed > for some reason it had full text selected so I switched to excerpt. Still, it's been hours since I've done this and the feed still displays the full text. Is it a matter of time for the feed to be updated with the new settings or is there other problem?

PS: I didn't write the snippet, I don't know PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$post->post_content` instead of `get_the_content()` since global $post are declared.